# Installing software by ./configure, make, make install

Tags: software-installation, non-root-user

I have access to a computer through SSH, and need to install Davinci Resolve without the root access. I only have access to the command line, and cannot use `sudo` for installation.

The documentation of the computer says that I have to use

```
./configure
make
make install
```

to install a software. The problem is that when I check Davinci Resolve installation file, there is not `configure` file. Instead there is only a `*.run` file.

I tried to use `autoconf`, but got

```
ERROR: end of file in string.
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some details. What operating system are you running? What is Davinci Resolve, where do you get it and what is its "installation file"?

Comment: Are you following the instructions here? https://github.com/flolu/davinci-resolve-linux  If not, then let us know a bit more about what it is you're doing. It's difficult to reproduce an issues with an unknown piece of software if one doesn't even know where to get the correct information to start working on it.

Comment: I suspect a `*.run` file is executable.  You should `./*.run` to install it.  However as it is a binary executable, you don't really know what it's doing and you are really trusting the author.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the "./configure,make,make install" will install the files in the /usr/local/ directory tree.  Since you said that you do not have root access, you can not install it there.  You could try installing it a directory that you have permission for with the command:

```
make install DESTDIR=<dir>
```

The will install the files in /etc, /bin, etc.